# Is "leave of absence" a countable noun?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Normally, if a word is generally uncountable ("English vocabulary"), but sometimes it becomes countable to convey particularity or variety ("the many vocabularies of various English dialects"), it'll be labeled as [U, C] in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, or as [uncountable or countable] in the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English. The noun *leave* is, thus, only uncountable, as it's only labeled as [U] and [uncountable]. I even consulted [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leave_of_absence), and it's still labeled as uncountable, with no plural form given. And yet, this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leave_of_absence) employs a host of singular and plural forms of *leave of absence*.

So could *leave of absence* ever be countable and take a singular form as *a leave of absence* and a plural form as *leaves of absence*?

Comment: But though "leave of absence" is a set phrase, it is not strictly speaking a compound, not a single word, therefore it is neither a count noun nor a non-count noun, but a composite nominal with "leave" as head and "of absence" as its complement. It can be pluralised: "leaves of absence", but grammatically it's no different to innumerable similar examples of noun + _of_ PP complement, like "cup(s) of tea" or "head(s) of state,

Comment: I googled the phrase, "a leave of absence", I got 1,660,000 results. This means something, doesn't it?

Comment: @BillJ Actually the phrase "leave of absence" is the only one I'm aware of to have a whole Wikipedia dedicated to it with various uses of "a leave of absence" and "leaves of absence". It's just the easiest one to find significant counter-examples of. Yes, it all comes down to the countability of the word "leave" alone.

Comment: Note that 'be countable' and 'exist in plural form' are not equivalent. 'Clothes' is plural-form but non-count. 'Police' is singular-form, non-count in general usage, but takes plural agreement. You need to distinguish 'plural-form' and 'taking a plural verb-form'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Edited, clarified. Also, police appears to be singular, but it's labeled as plural in the LDOCE. There's even a grammar note that specifically says "Police and the police are plural"

Comment: Unless it spells out its terminology in this article, LDOCE is being loose here. 'Police' is non-count (one mouse, two mice //**one police, three police) but takes plural agreement.

Comment: "Police" is a quasi-count noun. It cannot be used with low numerals, but is found with high round numerals. So you can say "200 police arrived", but not *3 police arrived".

Comment: @BillJ A quick check of the CGEL conceptual index doesn't give 'quasi-count noun', and a Google search only gives your article on English forums and an old article of mine on WW giving a different scare-quoted slant (and which I've now altered). Have you a reference using the term? The 'police' and 'cattle' idiosyncracies are fascinating.

Comment: @BillJ Are you sure about that? I think it's possible that such an expression as "200 police" is a *contraction* of "200 members of the police". Contractions like this are quite common in card games, RPGs and strategy games ("500 damage", "2 life", "4 mana").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the noun phrase *leave of absence* is countable, with the plural being *leaves of absence*. This is confirmed by the following dictionary example, despite the entry marking the head noun *leave* as a mass noun.

> **leave** *noun2 (mass noun)*
>   1 Time when one has permission to be absent from work or from duty in the armed forces.
>   ‘Full-time officers of research may take leaves of absence according to the policies described below.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/leave)

Suppose one goes *on leave* for medical reasons, and upon the period's expiry takes personal leave, they are *on leave* (non-count) for the whole duration. They aren't on (*) *two* leaves. Likewise, if another person takes some time off as well, we still say that the *two* people are *on leave* (still non-count). It's non-count because it refers to a *state* of their employment. There is no change to the state even if multiple episodes are ganged together.

Since *on leave* refers to state, it doesn't become plural even when talking about separate, non-consecutive episodes. One says that someone has been *on leave twice*, not that they have been on (*) *two leaves*.

However, a *leave of absence* is understood as a defined episode:

> A leave of absence (LOA) is a period of time that one must be away from one's primary job, while maintaining the status of employee. This contrasts with normal periods away from the workplace, such as vacations, holidays, hiatuses, sabbaticals, and "working from home" programs, in that they are considered exceptional circumstances, rather than benefits. Generally such an arrangement has a predefined termination at a particular date or after a certain event has occurred.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leave_of_absence)

Because these episodes can be counted, the term *leave of absence* is treated as countable.

(*) The asterisk is a convention that ELU uses to flag instances of non-grammatical usage.

Comment: How could a mass-only noun have a plural form? Is this a legit, grammatically correct example, or is the dictionary just being prescriptive or outdated in assigning the "mass" quality to the noun *leave*?

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw When *leave* is used on its own, I think it's fair enough to consider it a mass noun. Here, however, it's part of a noun phrase. It's really the *noun phrase* that is countable.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw My suspicion (and I don't have any substantiation for this - it's just *my* take on it) is that while "taking leave" is easily understood, "taking leave of absence" tends to get parsed as 'going away' from 'absence', which isn't what it means. Adding "a" before "leave" makes the parsing much more natural: "taking a leave of absence". Being able to have *one* of them, of course, opens the door to treating *leave of absence* as countable.

Comment: Google Books has over 1000 written instances of [*took **leaves** of absence*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=+%22leaves+of+absence%22#tbm=bks&q=%22took+leaves+of+absence%22), and obviously there would be vastly more if I hadn't included the specific word ***took***. I don't understand why this question even needs to be *asked*, but the answer is straightforward.

Comment: Does mass noun always mean uncountable only? The classic mass noun is "water", but it can be plural in the right context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Using Google alone to attest uses can be useful at times, but ultimately, still not as reliable as scientific surveys or confirmation from a grammatically inclined person. Not to mention a lot of people may actually be using the ungrammatical phrase (grammar police exist for a reason, don't they?). You can't just throw in a bunch or random examples that may not be reliable and call that citation.

Comment: @DJClayworth A quick look into the LDOCE tells me that "waters" has its own set of idiomatic meanings. "Waters" doesn't seem to mean "various types of water" in the same way that "fruits" means "various types of fruit", or "meats" or "sauces" for that matter.

Comment: This example does not confirm countability according to the most sensible usage of the term (this is the CGEL position, for example, and has been given on ELU several times). Non-count nouns may on occasion be preceded by a/an, but count nouns **must** be able to be preceded by a cardinal number. Thus 'groceries' is plural-form but non-count.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw After Edwin's comment, I've added to my answer.

Comment: @Vun-Hugh Vaw: Let's not forget that I'm a perfectly competent native speaker, so I already ***know*** what is or isn't "acceptable" use of English without needing to refer to "scientific surveys or confirmation from a grammatically inclined person". Regardless of "rules", *I took three leaves of absence last year* is a perfectly valid (if perhaps less common) alternative to *I took leave of absence three times last year*. BUT although *I took leave twice last month* is also fine, you'd probably never hear *I took two leaves last month*. If you want to understand why that is, *ask on **ELL**.*